# Windows upgrade from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 fails with "You can’t do a typical upgrade ..."

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to upgrade a server I ran into the following message:

> You can’t do a typical upgrade using an installation disc that’s
>   different from the language installed on your computer.

Existing OS:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Installed with a German DVD
- English Language Pack installed
- UI language is English with German number formats

Target OS:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- English DVD

Interpreting the message literally it appears to be false: The English language is installed contrary to what the message says.

**What can I do to in-place upgrade the OS?**

I'm testing the upgrade in a VM that was created from a server image. I'm open to performing experiments.

Comment: Pretty sure that error message means you need a German Server 2012 R2 DVD.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a Language Pack install doesn't completely change the language/localization of a Windows install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 2012R2 will only allow you to upgrade in the same language as the installation you're upgrading from. For whatever reason, this is by design. (I got this from the MS Exam Ref 70-410, page 12). The only way you're going to get an in-place upgrade to work is with a German version of the OS.

For further consideration, in case it assists anyone else:

The only possible upgrade path to Windows Server 2012 R2 is if the previous OS is the same base language, same platform (x86 or x64), not Itanium, and not a Pre-RTM edition of 2012. Also you can't upgrade from any workstation OS.

In Windows Server 2012 R2 Inside Out, the author strongly recommends migrating to a clean installation rather than upgrading in most cases, since in particular not all roles and features can be upgraded.